# ES6 Inheritance From Imported Module in Webpack

Tags: javascript, inheritance, webpack, es6-class

So I'm having issues with sub-classes extending a super class in Webpack.

My super class: core/Main.js

```
class Main {
    constructor () {
        console.log('Main Class Initialized');
    }
}

module.exports = Main;
```

Sub-class:  app/Launch.js

```
var Main = require('core/Main.js');
class Launch extends Main {

    constructor () {
        console.log('Before Super')
        super();
        console.log('Launch Class Initialized')
    }
}
```

If I `console.log(Main)` inside of the app/Launch.js file it logs Main and 'Before Super' also gets logged, but calling `super()` causes it to break and I have no idea why.

[How to achieve inheritance in ES6 with “webpack module bundler”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35974619/how-to-achieve-inheritance-in-es6-with-webpack-module-bundler) didn't help. I tried swapping out `module.exports` for `export class Main {}` and `require('core/Main.js')` for `import {Main} from 'core/Main.js'`, but it didn't work. Using webpack 1.14.0.

Comment: Inheritance has nothing to do with webpack. It seems your question is actually something like "how do I correctly import modules when using webpack" ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it. I copied `Main.js` into `app/` and required that. Works fine now, don't know why that made a difference though.

Comment: I don't know what's your project structure but if app and core folders are at the same level, the path that you are using in your Launch.js file to require Main.js is wrong, it should be '../core/Main.js'

Comment: So the structure is src/app and src/core. Where I set the context in the config to src so that I can call require('app/file') require('core/file') - which the context works for everything else in my project, but for some reason not in this case with src/core.